# Swiper slider with hide and show text conditions with slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have built a swiper slider here at https://codepen.io/pen?template=PoazjGz and there are 2 texts and 1 button. I want to show "swipe text" on all slides except the third one which class is "setting-up--active-col" and on the third one I want to show "Final Text and button". Inshort, hide swipe text on third slide and show final text and button.

```
    var activeCol = document.querySelector('.setting-up--active-col');
    var finalText = document.querySelector('.setting-up--final-text');
    var finalBtn = document.querySelector('.setting-up--btn');
    var swipeText = document.querySelector('.setting-up--swipe-text');
    
    // hide elements
    finalText.style.display = 'none';
    finalBtn.style.display = 'none';
    swipeText.style.display = 'none';
    
    // conditions
    if (activeCol.classList.contains('swiper-slide-active')){
        finalText.style.display = 'block';
        finalBtn.style.display = 'block';
            
    } else {
            swipeText.style.display = 'block';
        }
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and you have to made some little changes in your code.

Here is new code :

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-initialize', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container swiper-initialize">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14026383/pexels-photo-14026383.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="">
       <h2 class="setting-up--swipe-text">Swipe Text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13696285/pexels-photo-13696285.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="">
      <h2 class="setting-up--swipe-text">Swipe Text</h2>
    </div>
   
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6483585/pexels-photo-6483585.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
      <h2 class="setting-up--final-text">Final Text</h2>
      <button class="setting-up--btn">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5232929/pexels-photo-5232929.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
      <h2 class="setting-up--swipe-text">Swipe Text</h2>

    </div>
    

  </div>

  <!-- Buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rohit to look into this. The code is working well but this is not what I'm actually looking for.

I don't want to slide "Swipe Text" for every slide, the text will be there on the page below of the slider only change to "Final Text" when slider reached at slide 3.